# how can I reduced the speed of the narrator in Microsoft Lumia 540?

Tags: windows-10-mobile, narrator, accessibility

I can't reduced the speed of the narrator. I have tried every processes. But the volume  increased.there are no signs of decreasing.what can I do now?please help me.

Answer (score 3):

You can control the speed of the narrator using a slidebar.

1. Open Settings.
2. Go to Ease of Access -> Narrator.
3. You could see a slider under the speed option.
4. Drag the slider to increase or decrease the speed of the narrator.